# Cascading primitive type values to Blazored.Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazored

[Blazored.Modal's document](https://blazored.github.io/Modal/usage/passing-data) is very helpful in regards to passing parameters from "base" to modal. However, We have some trouble to update primitive types from base to modal.

In base (which will call the modal) we have

```
    [CascadingParameter]
    public bool IsTodayFriday { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public Employee employee { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public IModalService iModal { get; set; } = default!;
```

And to pass parameters to Modal:

```
        var emp= new Employee();
        var parameters = new ModalParameters()
            .Add(nameof(emp), emp)
            .Add(nameof(IsTodayFriday ), IsTodayFriday );
        
        iModal.Show<CheckDateAndLeaveEarly>("Get off early?", parameters);
```

In the Modal.razor.cs, decorate the parameters properly:

```
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsTodayFriday { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Employee employee{ get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public IModalService iModal { get; set; } = default!;
```

And that will pass all necessary parameters to the modal. However, the "IsTodayFriday " is passed by value instead of reference, so when the source changed, this value remains the same. I think I can wrap it up in some sort of object and pass by reference. But is there a simpler way to cascade the primitive type values?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0 shouldn't parameters be declared as cascading in the child component?

Comment: @maciek I tried to use [cascadingparameter] but it doesn't work. It seems blazored.Modal doesn't work as a child component.

Comment: Your use of `nameof()` seems strange. Does it even work for emp/employee?

Comment: "wrap it up in some sort of object" : Yes, this calls for a ViewModel. How do you handle Cancel?

Comment: Create a data class that contains your data (`IsTodayFriday` and `Employee`,... ).  Cascade that object and pass it as a `ModalParameter` into the modal.